# A possible generalization of an olympiad problem

Tags: combinatorics

I was trying my hands on a combinatorics problem from 1978 IMO . The problem was about a conference  in which there were delegates from six nations . Corresponding to every delegate there was an integer from {1,2,3...1978}. The goal was to prove that there exists at least one member whose corresponding integer is the sum of the corresponding integers of two members from his own country . 
I tried solving this problem and thought of first trying to prove that there exists atleast one member such that it's corresponding integer is the product of G.C.D of the corresponding integers of two members of his own country .
Suppose $\ n $ is the integer corresponding to a particular member and $\ x$ and $\ y $ are integers corresponding to two of the other members from the same country ,then we need to check whether there exists two integers $\ p $ and $\ q $ such that $\ p $$\ x$ + $\ q $$\ y $ =$\ n $. (to check if some set turns out to be linearly dependent).
Save for the case where both $\ p $ and $\ q $ are equal , is this generalization true . What number $\ k $ <1978 would suffice to make this generalization true ?

Comment: Huh? Why was that not a problem from 1994?

Comment: What do you mean by "the product of G.C.D of the corresponding integers"? The gcd is just one number; what are the factors in the product?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Actually, the problem is form 1978 and the 1994 should be 1978.

Comment: @joriki : for a certain ,n, n can be expressed as px+qy , where x and y are from the same country and p and q are integers . So, let's see if there are linearly dependent sets.

Comment: I see. You should clarify that in the question. Even after you explained it I don't see how the question can be interpreted to mean that.